# Holding magnet near CRT monitor damages the screen?

Tags: electromagnetism

Few days ago I tried keeping my magnet in front of my CRT monitor screen and it was showing some cool effects like showing so many different color but then when I removed it ,that blurr effect was still there and I thought I damaged my CRT monitor ? But why this happen ? Is there any damage caused by that magnet ?

Comment: To fix it, just degauss your monitor (your favorite search engine can tell you the specifics for your particular monitor). But note that those questions about there monitor aren't physics questions. The question about why it happens is a physics question.

Comment: And Kyle gives you a clue as to why: "de-gauss" your monitor. That means "remove magnetism". So what became magnetized? It's not the glass in the screen. Is it the phosphors?